# Importing Text File Loop while adding file name

Tags: vba, excel, filenames

I'm a newbie to Excel VBA and having some problem.  I am creating a Macro which will take a .dat file (imports like a .txt file) and puts the filename in the first row and then all the data underneath it starting with row 2.  Then the program loops and starts the process again 3 rows over (the data has many rows but only 3 columns).

Currently my Macro will put the imported data correctly, but the filename is not looping correctly.  It will input the filename into A1, loops inputs filename into D3 while deleting filename from A1.  I can't figure out what's going wrong.

```
Sub ImportDataFiles()
'call out variables
Dim fName As String, LastCol As Long, fileName As String, fso As Object

'loop start
BEGINNING:
LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
fName = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files, *.dat")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fileName = fso.GetFilename(fName)
'fileName is just the file name from the path
Range(Cells(1, LastCol).Address).Value = fileName
If fName = "False" Then Exit Sub
        'Imports data from text file
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & fName, _
            Destination:=Cells(2, LastCol))
                .TextFileStartRow = 30
                .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
                .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
                .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
                .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
                .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
                .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
                .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
                   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
                   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
                   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
                'loop end
                If MsgBox("Do you want to do it again?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then GoTo BEGINNING
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to add something to `LastCol` otherwise you're going to keep overwriting the previous values...

Comment: It also seems using `End(xlToLeft).Columns` instead of `End(xlUp).Rows`, you intend to align text file data side by side instead of stacking on top of each other. Usually, data and reports are handled in long not wide formats. See [Bruin's note here](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm).

Comment: @Tim-Williams, could you explain more?  Are you suggesting a meaningless increment because the LastCol will align with the data import.

Comment: @Parfait, I tried replacing with End(xlUp).Rows but it didn't seem to compile.

Answer (score 0):

This will get the column number of the last *occupied* cell in Row1 (or the first cell if there's nothing on the row)

```
LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

If you start populating content at that position you will (except in the empty row case) overwrite the content in that cell.

```
 LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column  + 1
```

Gives you the first *empty* cell [from the right] on that row.  But that doesn't account for the content in the imported file, which has multiple columns.  If your imported file has 3 columns then you need to offset further...

Answer (score 0):

To change from wide to long format, simply change the `LastCol` to `LastRow` with changes to the following four lines in code.

```
Dim ... LastRow As Long, ...

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
...
Range(Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Address).Value = fileName
...
   Destination:=Cells(LastRow + 2, 1))
```

This also resolves your overwriting of FileName and allows you to continue on with subsequent .dat file imports.